# Is it possible to obtain the atomic indices of a bond by clicking on a MoleculePlot?

Tags: graphics, chemistry

Consider the following `MoleculePlot`:

```
MoleculePlot["ammonia", Bond[{1, 2}]]
```

Its output is the following:

[image: MoleculePlot["ammonia"]]

I have highlighted `Bond[{1, 2}]` in the image above. But what I would actually like to do is to click on any bond and print the atomic indices of the atoms constituting that bond. So, for example, I would to see the message:

```
Bond[{1, 2}, "Single"]
```

when I click on that bond.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First a few basic observations. Mousing over the diagram in the summary box shows tooltips with the atom indices. That also works with MoleculePlot.

[image]

There is a WFR that lets one click on atoms in 3D to create a list of indices: [SelectAtoms3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SelectAtoms3D/).

For a bond and button, looks like this does not work, perhaps it will in the future:

```
MoleculePlot["ammonia",
Button[Bond[{1,2}],Print[Bond[{1,2},"Single"]]]]
```

But those things work in **Graphics** which is your output. So a simple trick is possible if you know what your element is in **Graphics** (run **InputForm** on your **Graphics** object to explore):

```
MoleculePlot["ammonia",Bond[{1,2}]]/.
x_StadiumShape:>Button[x,Print[Bond[{1,2},"Single"]]]
```

[image]

You can also do something like

```
MoleculePlot["ammonia",Bond[{1,2}]]/.
x_StadiumShape:>PopupWindow[x,Bond[{1,2},"Single"]]
```

[image]

You can explore docs further with **Tooltip** and **MouseAnnotation** and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can use `StadiumShape` until Wolfram Research does indeed allow `Button`.